# How to pass multidimensional arrays between Java and C++, with SWIG ?

Tags: java, c++, multidimensional-array, java-native-interface, swig

I would like to send a multidimensional array (`short[][]` in Java, `short int[][]` in C++) from Java code to C++ code, to process some coputations, then get back the array in Java code !

It works fine for one-dimensional arrays.

example.i :

```
%module example

%{
#include <iostream>
#include "example.h"
%}

%typemap(jtype) short int values[] "short[]"
%typemap(jstype) short int[] "short[]"
%typemap(javain) short int values[] "$javainput"
%typemap(jni) short int values[] "jshortArray"
%typemap(in) short int values[] {
  jboolean isCopy;
  $1 = JCALL2(GetShortArrayElements, jenv, $input, &isCopy);
}

%typemap(in,numinputs=0,noblock=1) int *data_len {
   int temp_len;
   $1 = &temp_len;
}


%typemap(jstype) const short int *CPPtoJava "short[]"
%typemap(jtype) const short int *CPPtoJava "short[]"
%typemap(jni) const short int *CPPtoJava "jshortArray"

%typemap(javaout) const short int *CPPtoJava {
  return $jnicall;
}


%typemap(out) const short int *CPPtoJava {
  $result = JCALL1(NewShortArray, jenv, temp_len);
  JCALL4(SetShortArrayRegion, jenv, $result, 0, temp_len, $1);
}



%include "example.h"
```

example.h :

```
class Test
{
public:

    short int* data;
    size_t l;

    void JavaToCPP(short int values[], size_t len) {
        this->l = len;
        this->data = values;
    }

    const short int *CPPtoJava(int *data_len){
        *data_len = this->l ;
        return this->data;
    }

    void process(){
        for(int i = 0 ; i< this->l ; i++){
            this->data[i] = i;
        }
    }


};
```

MainRunner.java

```
public class MainRunner {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        System.load("/path/to/../libexample.so");

        short in[] = {0,0,0};
        System.out.println("\nInput : ");
        for (int i = 0; i < in.length; ++i) {
              System.out.print(in[i] + "\t");
        }


        Test t = new Test(); 
        t.JavaToCPP(in,(long)in.length);
        t.process();


        short[] out = t.CPPtoJava();
        System.out.println("\n\nOutput : ");
        for (int i = 0; i < out.length; ++i) {
              System.out.print(out[i] + "\t");
        }
      }
}
```

Do you know how to handle mutlidimensional arrays in Swig ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Is `std::vector` an option? Makes things way simpler

Answer (score 1):

I created a header file to illustrate the kind of cases where you might want to use this. To support non-square 2D arrays it has `w` and `h` as the two size parameters for the output function.

It's slightly simpler than your example case and targeting C, not C++ (but the beauty of the JCALLx macros is they work for either language). (NB: If you're using C++ just use `std::array` or `std::vector` as appropriate 
instead and get all the wrapping for free).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

short **CPPtoJava(size_t *w, size_t *h) {
  *w = 3;
  *h = 4;
  short **data = malloc(sizeof(short*) * *w);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < *w ; ++i) {
    data[i] = malloc(sizeof(short) * *h);
    for (size_t j = 0; j < *h; ++j) {
      data[i][j] = (1+i)*(1+j);
    }
  }
  return data;
}

void JavaToCPP(short **values, size_t w, size_t h) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < w; ++i) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < h; ++j) {
      printf("(%zu, %zu): %d\n", i, j, (int)values[i][j]);
    }
  }
}
```

With that in place we can write some typemaps to marshal the data in and out of Java. They're not much different to the 1D case, except that we setup and build N 1D arrays and 1 array of arrays.

```
%module test

%{
#include "test.h"
#include <assert.h>
%}

// For the outputs
%typemap(jni) short ** "jobjectArray"
%typemap(jstype) short ** "short[][]"
%typemap(jtype) short ** "short[][]"
%typemap(javaout) short ** {
  return $jnicall;
}
%typemap(in,numinputs=0) size_t *w %{
  size_t w=0;
  $1 = &w;  
%}
%typemap(in,numinputs=0) size_t *h %{
  size_t h=0;
  $1 = &h;
%}
%typemap(out) short ** {
  $result = JCALL3(NewObjectArray, jenv, w, JCALL1(FindClass, jenv, "[S"), NULL);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < w; ++i) {
    jshortArray cur = JCALL1(NewShortArray, jenv, h);
    JCALL4(SetShortArrayRegion, jenv, cur, 0, h, $1[i]);
    JCALL3(SetObjectArrayElement, jenv, $result, i, cur);
  }
  free(result); // Since I called malloc this is needed
}


// For the inputs

%typemap(jni) (short **values, size_t w, size_t h) "jobjectArray"
%typemap(jstype) (short **values, size_t w, size_t h) "short[][]"
%typemap(jtype) (short **values, size_t w, size_t h) "short[][]"
%typemap(javain) (short **values, size_t w, size_t h) "$javainput"
%typemap(in,numinputs=1,noblock=1) (short **values, size_t w, size_t h) {
  $2 = JCALL1(GetArrayLength, jenv, $input);
  $1 = alloca(sizeof(short*) * $2); // Or maybe not on stack if you prefer?
  $3 = 0;
  if ($2 > 0) {
    jshortArray dim1 = JCALL2(GetObjectArrayElement, jenv, $input, 0);
    $3 = JCALL1(GetArrayLength, jenv, dim1);
  }

  for (size_t i = 0; i < $2; ++i) {
    jshortArray cur = JCALL2(GetObjectArrayElement, jenv, $input, i);
    assert((size_t)JCALL1(GetArrayLength, jenv, cur) == $3); // TODO: handle error
    $1[i] = JCALL2(GetShortArrayElements, jenv, cur, NULL);
  }
}
%typemap(freearg) (short **values, size_t w, size_t h) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < $2; ++i) {
    jshortArray cur = JCALL2(GetObjectArrayElement, jenv, $input, i);
    JCALL3(ReleaseShortArrayElements, jenv, cur, $1[i], JNI_ABORT);
  }
}

%include "test.h"
```

There's an assert hiding in there to prevent people from creating irregularly shaped (i.e. non-rectangular 2D arrays)

With that in place we can then run:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class run {
  private static void print(short[][] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr[i]));
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] argv) {
    System.loadLibrary("test");
    short[][] r1 = test.CPPtoJava();
    print(r1);
    test.JavaToCPP(r1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why is the .i so complicated? I cannot make any sense out of it. Are there really 7 typemaps JUST for CPPtoJava() ?

Comment: They all get used in different bits of the generated code. So if you want all of them to be non default then you need them. I'd suggest changing them one by one and using grep to see where they end up in the output if you're curious to see where they're needed. There usually is a simpler way to write code with fewer typemaps but the result is less idiomatic.

Comment: Where is the difference between %typemap and %apply explained ?

Comment: http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Typemaps.html#Typemaps_nn48 is probably the best reference point on it. At a high-level `%apply` copies all the typemaps that currently exist for a given type to another type, at that point in processing.

Comment: Thanks. But shouldn't it be simpler to use `carrays.i` or `arrays_java.i` ?